# How to create a function that checks if a property exists in an object?

Tags: javascript, function, object, properties, conditional-statements

My task is to create a function that checks if a specific property exists in object. I don't understand why the second log returns false when 'b' obviously exists in numbers object. Would be very happy if someone can explain the solution to me :)

```
const existInObject = (obj = {}, prop) => {
    for (const key in obj) {
      if(key === prop) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
};

const numbers = { 
    a: 5,
    b: 4,
}

const result1 = existInObject(numbers, "a");
const result2 = existInObject(numbers, "b");

console.log(result1, result2); // true, false
```

Comment: Doesn't the built-in `hasOwnProperty()` method do what you want?

Comment: You're returning on the first iteration, so you're only checking if the first property matches, not if any object matches.

Comment: `const existInObject = (obj = {}, prop) => obj.hasOwnProperty(prop);` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is because what Barmar said, *"You're returning on the first iteration, so you're only checking if the first property matches, not if any object matches"*. You have to go through all the keys to see if there's a match and return the result after that.

```js
const existInObject = (obj = {}, prop) => {
    var result = false;
    for (const key in obj) {
      if(key === prop) {
        result = true;
      }
    }
    return result
};

const numbers = { 
    a: 5,
    b: 4,
}

const result1 = existInObject(numbers, "a");
const result2 = existInObject(numbers, "b");
const result3 = existInObject(numbers, "c");

console.log(result1, result2, result3); // true, true, false
```